# Is it possible to use the capture groups from the regex of an express route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

I'm working on a fairly large node/express app using the GOV.UK Prototyping Kit. I have separated multiple instances of the prototype into standalone versions for archival purposes e.g. this isn't a build it once 'DRY' approach but rather there's quite a bit of duplication as the prototypes evolve (sometimes significantly). The crucial thing is that each version e.g. /phase/release/ is suitably separated.

I've separated the routes quite nicely but the final thing that would help would be to have a dynamic route.use -> require so that I don't have to manually update the top-level routes.js file for each version release.

I use regex matching in my routes quite a lot so I'm fairly familiar with that, but what I'm wondering is how I can use the details of the match to dynamically build the require. Or perhaps use something in `req.params` - but I don't think that's available outside of a route.

Here's an outline of my code. The static route (R1) works fine but neither of the dynamic routes (R2/R3) work (when uncommented):

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.use('/:phase/:release', function (req, res, next) {

  // Make phase and release available in subsequent routes
  let prototype = {}
  prototype.phase = req.params.phase
  prototype.release = req.params.release
  req.session.data.prototype = prototype

  next()

})

// Phase/release specific routes
// -----------------------------

// R1. This works
router.use('/test/a/', require('./views/test/a/_routes.js'));

// R2. But a dynamic version world be better?...
// router.use(/(alpha|beta|test)\/([abc])\//, require('./views/' + \1 + '/' + \2 '/_routes.js'));
// R3. ...or...
// router.use('/:phase/:release/', require('./views/' + req.params.phase + '/' + req.params.release '/_routes.js'));
```

Ultimately I think my approach is wrong and that it's not possible to reference the regex capture groups this way, but equally I don't think I can access the `req` object (and therefore `req.params`) as part of the require path.

I would expect there to be a way to use information known prior to making the require within the constructed require path but I just can't work out how.

Any input/help much appreciated.

Comment: ` + \1 + ` in javascript actually means `+ 1 +` since the backslash is for escaping, in this case the number 1, thus not beeing interpreted as captured group. there is no code around that expression that tells javascript to handle it as result of a regex group. to let javascript know that you want to access the latter, you must quote it AND use it within a function that accepts a group. _router.use()_ is not such a function, that passes a group result from the first argument to the second. so, storing your captured groups into a variable first would be best, I guess. Try `"yourString".match()`

Comment: Thanks @meistermuh. That approach didn't work for me but I think I was attempting to construct information that couldn't be known at that point anyway. :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope i understand your question correctly.

If the _routes.js exports a router which is essentialy a function which accepts **req, res, next** params then you can do this:

```
router.use('/:phase/:release/', function(req, res, next){

    var anotherRouter = require('./views/' + req.params.phase + '/' + req.params.release '/_routes.js');
    anotherRouter(req, res, next);

});
```

Comment: Excellent, that's what I was missing thanks @Molda. It had dawned on me that my original idea/approach was never going to work because I was trying to construct a route before I knew where the user actually wanted to go! (In which scenario, I have seen other suggestions that load 'all possible routes' by recursively loading files). However, the method you've suggested enables the loading of a specific route file within the `/phase/release/` match... just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

[Express documentation for router.get](https://expressjs.com/fr/4x/api.html#router.METHOD) documents in the last exemple that when you use a regex for the route parameter, the captured groups are available in req.params by position (tested on Express 4.17). This also works with a *required* router handler instead of a function (as you do), of course.

```
router.use(/(alpha|beta|test)\/([abc])\//, (req, res) => {
  console(req.params[0]); // will show the first captured group: alpha, beta or test
  console(req.params[1]); // will show the 2nd captured group
});
```